# Create dynamic attributes in a XSD

Tags: xsd

I want to create an XSD that let me has child node with additional attributes depending of the parent node.

For example: I have de tag  with the only attribute **name**, and also have the tag  and when the tag **Animal** where inside the tag **Oviparous** I want that  now has the attributes **name** and **eggSize**.

```
<Animal name="TheCat"/>
<Oviparous>
  <Animal name="TheChiken" eggSize="20">
</Oviparous>
```

Is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

For starters I'm going to assume you have a root node, and also that Animal node your TheChicken is self closing

```
<Animals>
    <Animal name="TheCat"/>
    <Oviparous>
        <Animal name="TheChiken" eggSize="20" />
    </Oviparous>
</Animals>
```

For that the following schema will describe it.  Note that the Animal node is defined in different locations with different attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Animals">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Animal">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Oviparous">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Animal">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="eggSize" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```